value error "No gradient provided for any variable", in custom loss function
I am fine-tuning an already trained model using a custom loss function. I am working on an audio related problem. When my input file has speech then the gradients are being calculated effectively for the file, but as soon as a file with no speech is encountered, I receive a no gradients provided error.  I am able to return a loss for that file but all the variables have a gradient of none for that file, independent of the scale of the loss I provide.  I checked if variables of the model were contributing to the input file, and yes they did transform the input file, removing noise from it. So the issue isn't that no variables are contributing to the input file transformation. I think there might be an error in how I am handling the case when formant and harmonic errors are not calculated from the respective True condition in the code.
 # Update the code snippet to calculate conditions for harmonic and formant errors
                is_voiced_h = tf.cond(
                    tf.logical_and(
                        tf.logical_and(i < num_frames - 1, tf.equal(speechs[i], 1)),
                        tf.logical_and(tf.equal(speechs[i], 1), tf.equal(speechs[i + 1], 1)
                                       )),
                    lambda: True,  # Condition met
                    lambda: False)  # Out of bounds or condition not met

                is_voiced_f = tf.cond(tf.logical_and(
                    tf.logical_and(i < num_frames - 1, tf.equal(speechs[i], 1)),
                    tf.logical_or(tf.equal(speechs[i + 1], 1), tf.equal(speechs[i + 2], 1))
                                    ),
                                      lambda: True,  # Condition met
                                      lambda: False)  # Out of bounds or condition not met

                is_unvoiced_f = tf.cond(tf.logical_and(tf.logical_and(i< num_frames - 2, tf.equal(speechs[i], 3)),
                                                       tf.logical_or(tf.equal(speechs[i + 1], 3),
                                                                     tf.equal(speechs[i + 2], 3))),
                                        lambda: True,  # Condition met
                                        lambda: False)  # Out of bounds or condition not met

                if i < (num_frames-2)//2:
                    not_flagged_f = tf.cond(tf.logical_and(i < num_frames - 2,  # Check out of bounds
                                                          tf.logical_or(tf.equal(flags[i], False),
                                                                        tf.logical_or(tf.equal(flags[i + 1], False),
                                                                                      tf.equal(flags[i + 2], False)))),
                                            lambda: True,   # Condition met
                                            lambda: False)  # out of bounds or condition not met
                else:
                    not_flagged_f = True

                pitch = process_audio_tf(ref_frame_h, sample_rate=sample_rate)
                pitch = pitch[0]
                epsilon = 1e-5
                harmonic_error = tf.cond(is_voiced_h,
                                         lambda: process_frame(ref_frame_h, model_frame_h, pitch, sample_rate),

                                         lambda: tf.zeros((1,), dtype=tf.float32)) + epsilon

                formant_error = tf.cond(tf.logical_and(tf.logical_or(is_voiced_f, is_unvoiced_f), not_flagged_f),
                                        lambda: calculate_formant_error(ref_frame_f, model_frame_f, sample_rate,
                                                                        formants[i:i + 1,...][0, 0],
                                                                        formants[i:i + 1,...][0, 1], n_fft),
                                        lambda: tf.zeros((8,), dtype=tf.float32)) + epsilon

                #tf.print('harmonic_error from body', harmonic_error)
                #tf.print('formant_error from body', formant_error)

                harmonic_errors = harmonic_errors.write(i, harmonic_error)
                formant_errors = formant_errors.write(i, formant_error)

                return i + 1, harmonic_errors, formant_errors

            _, harmonic_errors, formant_errors = tf.while_loop(lambda i, *_: i < num_frames, body, [0, harmonic_errors, formant_errors])
            harmonic_errors = harmonic_errors.stack()
            formant_errors = formant_errors.stack()


Your whole loss function is not differentiable.

@Dr.Snoopy, the gradient was not calculated for certain files only, so the differentiability wasn't the problem but the way i was handling the error of frames with no speech was. I was returning a constant error for frames with no speech and that was causing the graph to disconnect from the contributing variable in the layer. However, once i identified this the problem got solved. Thank you for your reply.
